# HP Smart Array B110i SATA RAID Controller drivers crash HP DL320 G6

Tags: installation, windows-server-2012-r2, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I'm trying to install Windows Server 2012R2 on a HP DL320 G6 with a Smart Array B110i SATA RAID Controller. During the install, it asks me to load the driver for the RAID, I load the drivers from [cp022401](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_2783ab4ebb604f4e91ab6652bc#tab1) (also tried [cp020545](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_468f229c80b344f1ac948770aa&swEnvOid=4024)) and the machine promptly crashes with the HP BIOS frowny face.

That particular server was running Hyper-V 2012 with no problem, so I know that the hardware is fine, I'm just replacing the old hard drives with newer/bigger ones.

Do you have any idea how to install the B110i drivers successfully on Win2012R2?

[image: Here's the driver that makes the server crash]
[image: Here's the message I get when the machine crashes]

Comment: Have you ran the latest SPP on the box?

Comment: I ran the lastest SPP (829873_001_spp_2015.06.0-SPP2015060.2015_0605.106.iso) on the machine and it freezes on the splash screen, whether I use auto or interactive... Maybe it's an hardware issue after all. :-/
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6t6hdrn2jbqsa5/2015-07-21%2015.35.59.jpg?dl=0

Comment: ok, my firmware was too old for SSP. SPP is now running, I'll keep you updated.
From http://blog.asiantuntijakaveri.fi/2014/11/upgrading-hp-proliant-firmware-is-easy.html:
"Next we need to use old "Smart Update Firmware DVD Proliant Support Pack v10.10" from 2012 because newer SPP is not compatible with older firmwares. Don't even think about using automatic upgrade either like Firmware DVD suggests when booting from ISO image as it will just end up getting stuck in X11 desktop with default cursor. Instead use manual mode and click thru dozens of Next Next Next dialogs."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, finally figured out what was wrong! Thanks to Chopper3 for pointing me in the right direction.

The problem is that the firmware was too old for the Windows Server 2012R2 B110i driver.

I had to upgrade the firmware using [Smart Update Firmware DVD Proliant Support Pack v10.10](https://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?idx=&ac.admitted=1407877024044.876444892.492883150&action=driverDocument&itemLocale=&swItemId=MTX_9ed665a89aba447d925937f38b&mode=) first, then I was able to run [SPP](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx) to get the latest version. After all that, the B110i driver ran fine.